# Solving a matrix equation with unknown inside trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, trace

Given $n \times n$ symmetric matrices $A, B, C$, how to solve the following matrix equation in $n \times n$ matrix $X$?

$$\mbox{tr} (AX) B + \mbox{tr} (BX) C + \mbox{tr} (CX) A = \mbox{tr} (AX) C + \mbox{tr} (BX) A + \mbox{tr} (CX) B$$

Comment: One natural approach would be to start by solving $xB+yC+zA=xC+yA+zB$. That's $n^2$ equations in $3$ unknowns, but at least $x=y=z$ will yield solutions; there might be more than that depending on $A, B, C$. Then you just need to find all the $X$ that give the right traces. If $n\ge 2$ there would be at least some nontrivial solutions.

Comment: The equation can be rewritten in the form of $\operatorname{tr}(PX)=\operatorname{tr}(QX)=0$ if $\dim\operatorname{span}\{A,B,C\}\ge2$, or $\operatorname{tr}(PX)=0$ if $\dim\operatorname{span}\{A,B,C\}\le1$. Therefore the general solution can be obtained from any $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ in the null space of $\pmatrix{\operatorname{vec}(P^T)&\operatorname{vec}(Q^T)}^T$ in the former case, or any $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ in the null space of $\operatorname{vec}(P^T)^T$ in the latter case.

Comment: @user1551 can you elaborate on how you write the equation in the form of $tr(PX)=tr(QX)=0$? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left((A-C)X\right)B
+\operatorname{tr}\left((B-A)X\right)C
+\operatorname{tr}\left((C-B)X\right)A=0.\tag{1}
$$
When $A,B,C$ are linearly independent, we must have
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left((A-C)X\right)
=\operatorname{tr}\left((B-A)X\right)
=\operatorname{tr}\left((C-B)X\right)=0.
$$
Since the three traces always sum up to zero, the above is equivalent to $\operatorname{tr}\left((A-C)X\right)=\operatorname{tr}\left((B-A)X\right)=0$. Thus the equation is equivalent to one in the form of
$$
\operatorname{tr}(PX)=\operatorname{tr}(QX)=0\tag{2}
$$
for some constant matrices $P$ and $Q$.

When $\dim\operatorname{span}\{A,B,C\}=2$, by writing one of $A,B,C$ as a linear combination of the other two, $(1)$ can also be rewritten in the form of $(2)$ (for some other $P$ and $Q$, of course). Therefore, the general solution can hence be obtained from any $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ in the null space of $\pmatrix{\operatorname{vec}(P^T)&\operatorname{vec}(Q^T)}^T$ when $\dim\operatorname{span}\{A,B,C\}\ge2$.

Similarly, when $\dim\operatorname{span}\{A,B,C\}\le1$, $(1)$ reduces to $\operatorname{tr}(PX)=0$ for some appropriate matrix $P$. Therefore, the general solution in this case is obtained from any $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ in the null space of $\operatorname{vec}(P^T)^T$.

Answer (score 2):

Define the linear map $f: \operatorname{Mat}_n \to \operatorname{Mat}_n$, by 
$$ f(X) = \operatorname{tr}((A-C)X)B + \operatorname{tr}((B-A)X)C + \operatorname{tr}((C-B)X)A.$$
Then, the solution to the problem is the kernel of $f$. We can see that the image of $f$ is always a symmetric matrix, and so the image is at most $\left(\frac{1}{2} n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n\right)$-dimensional, hence the kernel of $f$ is at least $\left( \frac{1}{2}n^2 - \frac{1}{2}n\right)$-dimensional, so there will always be solutions for $n \geq 2$.

You could find the solutions by writing down the linear map $f$ in some basis, and finding its null space.