# Solve for matrix trace equation

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

How to solve for $\mathbf X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ given:

$$
\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf P\mathbf X) = q\,,
$$

where $\operatorname{tr}$ is matrix trace, with $\mathbf P \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ and $q$ known? I'm aware of the existing question [Solving a matrix equation with unknown inside trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3247113/1057593). The difference is that $q$ is not limited to zero. Thanks!

Comment: Is $\mathbf{P}$ a known matrix?

Comment: If P is known, just manipulate the diagonal part of the SVD a bit

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf P$ is known. Could you elaborate the svd part? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $q=0$, choose $X=0$. Otherwise, let $P= U D V^T$ be the SVD with $D$ diagonal. Now simply choose $X=V Z U^T$ where $Z$ is also diagonal but $Z_{ii} = q/mD_{ii}$. This ensures that
$$\operatorname{tr}(PX) = \operatorname{tr}(UDV^T VZU^T) = \operatorname{tr}(DZ) = q$$
where we used the cyclic property of the trace and the fact that $U^T U = I$ and $V^T V = I$.

Comment: What if $q=0$? Is there non-trivial solution then?

Comment: Yes of course. In the same spirit as above, just choose a diagonal matrix $Z$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m Z_{ii} D_{ii} = 0$.

Comment: I see. So if let the diagonal elements of $D$ and $Z$ be $d$ and $z$, it all reduces to finding $z$ such that $d^\top z = q$. Since there can be infinitely many $z$, I only need to select one that suits possibly other constraints. Thank you so much!